# Handling stream from server and displaying the file in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I'm trying to find the global solution for handling strem files from the server.

My response object is angular http Response

My object has differnet _body for images/docs etc.

images is a long string of @#$.. and docs are json

I've been looking for solutions over the web, and got to implement this:

```
let contentType = resData.headers.get("Content-Type");
let blob = new Blob([resData.arrayBuffer()], {type: contentType});
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open('url: ', url);
```

This code downloads a file that has content-type of octet-stream
but all other files are not displayed in the browser.

My main goal is to have the same behavior if would have put in the URL the API that returns a stream, and the browser knows how to handle it (images are shown in browser, files that browser doesn't support are automatically downloaded etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the request.

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(Object.keys(RequestMethod).find(k => RequestMethod[k] === url.method), url.url, true);
            const shift = 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

            xhr.responseType = (Object.keys(ResponseContentType).find(k => ResponseContentType[k] === url.responseType)).toLocaleLowerCase();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        let blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: body.MimeType});
                        observer.next({blob: blob, fileName: body.FileName});
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.send(url.getBody());
```

This is the code for the special handling of each mimeType

```
handleAttachmentItem(resData) {
    let blob = resData.blob;
    const fileName = resData.fileName;
    if (blob.type.includes('image')) {
        let b64Response = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let outputImg = document.createElement('img');
        outputImg.src = b64Response;
        let w = window.open();
        w.document.write('<html><head><title>Preview</title><body style="background: #0e0e0e">');
        w.document.write(outputImg.outerHTML);
    } else if (blob.type.includes('text')) {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
    } else {
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
}
```